# Create a desktop app that generate ms word file

Tags: ms-word, win32com, office-automation

I'm now working with tons of MS Word files and trying to find a way in improving my workflow.

I'm wondering if there's a way to create a desktop app which can preview certain parts from a Word file, select them and generate a new one with controls in Word's text style, paragraph, etc.

I supposed that this would take MS Word API and some frame structure particularly. I've been using Electron/node.js to create some cross platform applications, wondering if it can do as well? Or is there any reference that I can dig in?

Sorry if this sounds like a rookie one. I've tried to search but still can't find out where to start.

Comment: This probably doesn't solve your problem, but it's useful to know regardless: Word files are essentially zip archives. If you change the file extension from .docx to .zip, you can look at the files that make up the word file... You can then edit the file content by editing the .xml files in that archive. The main document body is found under /word/document.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possible ways to get the job done:

1. Automate MS Word to get job done. See [Automate MS Office Applications using Python win32com module](https://kbarik.wordpress.com/2020/01/17/automate-ms-office-applications-using-python-win32com-module/) for more information. For example:

   ```
   import win32com.client

   word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
   ```
2. Use the Open XML SDK for generating Word documents at runtime, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.
3. Use third-party components.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, there seem to be some way to access Word files in Python: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/16/python-and-microsoft-office-using-pywin32/. Maybe in node too.